# Function that creates a table from two lists

Tags: functions, output-formatting, list-manipulation, core-language, output

I have two lists shown below:

list1 = {(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1),(0,0,1,0),...,(1,1,1,1)}
list2 = {1,5,5,5,...,5}

How can I construct a function that outputs a table similar to this:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Initial vector} & \text{Period} \\ \hline
(0,0,0,0) & 1 \\
(0,0,0,1) & 5 \\
(0,1,0,1) & 5 \\
(0,1,1,1) & 5 \\
\end{array}$$

I have experimented using Table, but it just outputs a list.

EDIT:

What is wrong with my function taken from one of the answers:

```
printPeriodTbl[vectors_, periods_] := 
  Grid[Prepend[
    Transpose[{Row[{"(", Row[#, ","], ")"}] & /@ vectors, 
      periods}], {"Initial Vector", "Period"}], 
   Dividers -> {2 -> True, 2 -> True}];
```

what I am passing into this function looks like:

```
vectors =  {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}
period = {1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5}
```

Errors from this are:

```
Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {Pattern[((Row[#1,,])&)[listOfInitVectors],(Row[_,,])],listOfPeriods_} cannot be transposed. >>
Transpose::tperm: Permutation {Pattern[((Row[#1,,])&)[listOfInitVectors],(Row[_,,])],listOfPeriods_} is longer than the dimensions {2} of the expression. >>
```

Comment: `Transpose[{list1,list2}]` then use `TableForm` and add your table headers

Comment: You have written `list1` as `{(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1),(0,0,1,0),...,(1,1,1,1)}`. Since you clearly know that lists are `{}` the only way to interpret this is that `(0,0,0,0)` must be a string. In other words `list1` and `list 2` are both vectors (hence `Transpose`). Is that actually what you mean or is it a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list1 = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}};
list2 = {1, 5, 5, 5};

Grid[Prepend[Transpose[{Row[{"(", Row[#, ","], ")"}] & /@ list1, list2}],
  {"Initial Vector", "Period"}], Dividers -> {2 -> True, 2 -> True}]
```

[image]

or

```
 Grid[Join[{{"Initial Vector", "Period"}}, 
            Transpose[{Row[{"(", Row[#, ","], ")"}] & /@ list1, list2}]] ,
      Dividers -> {2 -> True, 2 -> True}]
 (* same output *)
```

or

```
tbl = Table[{Row[{"(", Row[list1[[i]], ","], ")"}], list2[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length@list1}];
Grid[Prepend[tbl, {"Initial Vector", "Period"}], Dividers -> {2 -> True, 2 -> True}]
(* same  output *)
```

**Update:** If your `list1` is a list of strings like

```
 list1b = {"(0,0,0,0)", "(0,0,0,1)", "(0,0,1,0)", "(1,1,1,1)"}
```

then you can simply use `list1b` instead of `Row[{"(", Row[...],")"}]`.

Comment: Based on how the question was written I thought the only way to interpret `list1` was `{"(0,0,0,0})",...}` unless he is completely unfamiliar with Mma syntax.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, that makes more sense; makes it easier too.

Comment: Could you look at my edit please. I am confused on the issue

Comment: @connor, if your `list1` is a list of strings, e.g., `{"(0,0,0,0)", "(0,0,0,1)", "(0,0,1,0)", "(1,1,1,1)"}` then you don't need the `Row[....]` piece; you can just use `list1` instead of `Row[{"(", Row[#, ","], ")"}] & /@ list1`.

Comment: I actually turned them into lists, so it is currently a list of lists like {{0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1}}

Comment: @connor, in that case the function in your update is fine.

Comment: It is giving me errors though, I will show those in my edit now.

Comment: @connor,  the lists `vectors` and `period` should have the same length.

Comment: @kguler I found my mistake. I was using append instead of appendto in some spots. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: @connor, glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Grid[Prepend[Transpose@{list1, list2}, {"Initial Vector", "Period"}], Dividers -> {2 -> True, 2 -> True}]
```